# Programmatically setup a VPN

Tags: cocoa, macos, network-programming, vpn

How would I go about to programmatically setup a VPN that the Network settings in Mac OS X 10.5 and later can see?

Network settings is scriptable, but only starting and closing network interfaces. Not for creating and modifying.

A solution that Network settings can not see is not ideal, but close enough.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022250/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-connection-programmatically-in-mac